# What is the meaning of () in output console?

Tags: swift, swift5, swift-playground

**Problem Statement**

I am new to Swift and could not seem to get what `()` means that keeps showing up after each function call of my class.

**The Code**

```
import UIKit


class sample{
        //Member variables
        var number = 34
        var decimal = 3.5
        var subject = ""

        //Member method

        func printSentence(){
            number += 1
            print("The value of number is \(number)")
            print("Subject name: \(subject)")
        }

}

var o: sample = sample()

print(o.subject)
print(o.printSentence())
o.subject = "Swift Programming"

print(o.subject)
print(o.printSentence())
```

I do have an object-oriented background but I fail to decipher what `()` means that shows up in the Live Viewer and the Console on running my program. (Screenshot below)
[image: screenshotXCode]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's coming from this line:

```
print(o.printSentence())
```

`o.printSentence()` is a function that returns nothing, a.k.a. `()` or `Void`.

You probably meant to call the function, not print the function, instead:

```
o.printSentence() /// executes all the code inside `printSentence()`
```

Comment: Makes sense for it to show on Live Viewer but why does it display on the console tho? Can you please include that in your answer ?

Comment: @mishsx edited - I'm pretty sure you meant to do `o.printSentence()`.

Comment: Okay so if I try to print a function call that returns nothing, Swift shows that up as a `()`. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use the print method, change your function so it returns a string value. Then you print the String value :)

E.g.

```
class sample {
    var number = 34
    var decimal = 3.5
    var subject = ""

func printSentence(subject: String) -> (String){
    self.number+=1
    return ("The value of number is \(number)" + " and my subject name is \(subject)")
        
    }
}

var o: sample = sample()
print(o.number)


print(o.printSentence(subject: "Swift"))
print(o.number)
```

Output:

34

The value of number is 35 and my subject name is Swift

35